# RabbitMQ Shovel basic example

Tags: jms, rabbitmq, message-forwarding, rabbitmq-shovel

I am working on a basic example and am not able to work it out.

I need to forward messages from one machine (Machine1) to another (Machine2) via a queue (TestQ).
Producer is running on the Machine1 and a consumer on the Machine2.

My settings in the Machine1's rabbit broker config:

```
{rabbitmq_shovel, [ {shovels, [
    {shovel_test, [
        {sources, [{broker, "amqp://" }]},
        {destinations, [{broker, "amqp://Machine2" }]},
        {queue, <<"TestQ">>},
        {ack_mode, on_confirm},
        {reconnect_delay, 5}
    ]}
]} ]}
```

Machine2 has a default config and no shovel plugin enabled.

Producer's code running on the Machine1:

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
factory.setHost("localhost");
Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
Channel channel = connection.createChannel();       
channel.queueDeclare("TestQ", true, false, false, null);   
channel.basicPublish("", "TestQ", null, "Hello World!".getBytes());
```

Consumer's code running on the Machine2:

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
factory.setHost("localhost");
Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
channel.queueDeclare("TestQ", true, false, false, null);
QueueingConsumer consumer = new QueueingConsumer(channel);
channel.basicConsume("TestQ", true, consumer);

while (true) {
    QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery = consumer.nextDelivery();
    String message = new String(delivery.getBody());
    System.out.println(" [x] Received '" + message + "'");
}
```

Executing rabbitmqctl eval 'rabbit_shovel_status:status().' on the Machine1:

```
[{shovel_test,starting,{{2014,1,7},{9,47,38}}}]
...done.
```

Producer sends ok, but I never get a receive from the consumer on the Machine2.

Where is a problem? Something is missing in the conf of Machine1's broker, or Machine2's broker?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The status of your shovel should be `running`, not `starting`. If it stays in the `starting` phase, that means it can't start up correctly (e.g. can't connect to the destination broker).

One problem I spotted is that you used `broker` instead of `brokers` for specifying the list of sources. Try this:

```
{rabbitmq_shovel,
 [{shovels, [{shovel_test,
              [{sources, [{brokers, ["amqp://"]}]},
               {destinations, [{broker, "amqp://Machine2"}]},
               {queue, <<"TestQ">>},
               {ack_mode, on_confirm},
               {reconnect_delay, 5}
              ]}
            ]}
 ]}.
```

Comment: `brokers` is a valid option, actually the code is alright, I have found the problem in not opened port on the server. That solved everything.